# .NET web API from SQL, error: CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a simple .NET web API from a single SQL table and I'm running into this problem on the Controller development:

[image: Code for OptOutController.cs and error in bottom]

[image: This is the OptOut model]

[image: This is program.cs]

I have not yet tried anything because I am new to this.

Comment: Your function return a `Task<IActionResult<T>>` but you are returning a just a list.

Comment: The return type of your method should be something like Task<List<OptOut>>

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: could you pls let us know if you want to have a list as the response or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return an `ActionResult`:

> Error: cannot convert from List to ActionResult

The function return is

```
Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OptOut>>>
```

Wrap your return in an `Ok()` function call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clearly, when we need to `return _dbcontext.Model.ToListAsync();`, then we need to change the method return type. And if we want to return `Task<IActionResult<T>>`, then like what @aniekan said, we should `return Ok(_dbcontext.Model.ToListAsync())`;

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OptOut>>> getoutputs() {
    var res = await _context.OptOut.ToListAsync();
    return Ok(res);
}
```

Here I want to inform you a normal way to fix compile error with VS, using the **potential fix** feature...

[image]